# Print an accurate counter in golang while using goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

So I have my goroutines set up which are speeding up my requests in the function `request`. I'm trying to implement a counter which counts how many requests have been sent, but as goroutines sort of 'repeats' the process x amount of times it is difficult to make an accurate counter. Is there any other method, or does anyone know a way to accurately log the amount of requests sent?

Code:

```
func routine() {
    fmt.Println()
    rep := 1000
    results := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < rep; i++ {
        go func(num int) {
            results <- request(num)
        }(i)
    }

    for i := 0; i < rep; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-results)
    }
}

...

func request(num int) string {
    client := &http.Client{}
    count_checks := 0 

    for {
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://endpoint.com/users", nil)

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            print(err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        if contents != nil {
            count_checks++
            fmt.Println(count_checks)
    
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs as expected (1000x per number):

```
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to increment counters in goroutine save manner

https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic@go1.17.5#AddInt32

Examples are trivial

```golang
// count_checks := 0 
var count_checks int64 = 0

// your code here
// count_checks ++
sync.AddInt32(&count_checks, 1)
```